# Suggestion - Updates Notification Action

Tags: appcenter

The Updates Notification does nothing. It would make more sense if clicking on the notification would cause the application center to display the updates screen.

Answer (score 1):

It does.
I just got notified of an available update, clicked on the notification and the update screen opened.

Comment: On my sysyem, sometimes the AppCenter  opens when I click on a notification, sometimes do not.